# Customization of dendogram after using plot_dendogram function in igraph package

Tags: r, dendrogram, network-analysis

I am looking to plot a dendogram with 137 final nodes (I know it is alot, but it is for taxa within a microbial community). I can get the dendogram plotted, but the taxa identified as OTU"X", are crunched on the side and unreadable. Additionally, I want to make branches colored based on the cluster they are in.

I have tried is the plot_dendogram() function in igraph, then using the ape package for customization (see code below, some info may be extra but wanted to include in case helpful!). I am newer to R and having trouble understanding the documentation, so an explanation and some help would be greatly appreciated. I get error saying "unexpected symbol" in the plot_dendogram code line. I would like an output similar to the image here [desired dendogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnwHe.png).Thanks for any help in advance.

igraph documentation I am trying to follow and comprehend: https://r.igraph.org/reference/plot_dendrogram.communities.html

Code:

```
## Network Analysis ##
# set seed for reproducability #
set.seed(1)
# 
se.mb.phylo <- spiec.easi(phylo, method='mb', lambda.min.ratio=1e-2,
                          nlambda=100, pulsar.params=list(rep.num=50))
# Convert adjacency matrix into igraph object for analysis and plotting # 
ig.mb <- adj2igraph(getRefit(se.mb.phylo),  vertex.attr=list(name=taxa_names(phylo)))

## Hub Detection ##
net <- ig.mb
# Link-analysis methods (page_rank and hub_score below)
# output an object in which there is a vector containing the values for the nodes
net.pr <- page_rank(net)$vector
net.hs <- hub_score(net)$vector
# Centrality vectors can be sorted to select taxa with highest probability of being keystone species #
# Below orders taxa based on hub score, and selects top 10 taxa #
# Sort the species based on hubbiness score
net.hs.sort <- sort(net.hs, decreasing = TRUE)
# Choose the top 10 keystone species
net.hs.top10 <- head(net.hs.sort, n = 10)
View(net.hs.top10) #OTU53, 48, 101, 8, 68, 18, 37, 97, 100, 120
# Lets use two cluster detection methods from igraph package #
# igraph methods output an object containing various information on the detected clusters, #
# including but not limited to the membership of each cluster #
# Get clusters (two methods used below)
# walktrap.community is an approach based on random walks.
# Again, you can use the modularity score to select where to cut the dendrogram.
wt <- walktrap.community(net) #31 clusters detected
# Fast unfolding of communities in large networks, communities are not merged; 
# gets stuck (i.e. none of the nodes change their membership), then all the communities are collapsed 
# into single nodes and the process continues
ml <- multilevel.community(net) #30 clusters detected
# Get membership of walktrap clusters
membership(wt)
membership(ml)
# Plot clusters as dendrogram
plot_dendrogram(wt, mode="phylo", colbar = palette(),
            edge.color = NULL, use.edge.length = FALSE, \dots))
```